# Set Current Date when binding to SQL Server

Tags: binding

I need to auto populate the date in a textbox while binding to a data base.
Note I know how to set a binding as well as how to set current date. What I do not know is how to set both with one textbox.

This allows me to bind and save to DB, but not display current date:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateWorked" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateWorked","{0:d}")%>/>
```

This allows me to set date, but not bind:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateWorked" runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %> />
```

I need to do both and cannot find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the databind you can set the column value using:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
(pass now to your DB here)
```

To display without saving to the DB, you can set the textbox value in the pageload.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
txtDateTime.Text = String.Format("{0:t}", Now);
```

Comment: I am not binding in code behind but on the page in a form view. I can add a date and I can bind to DB. I just don't know the syntax to do both inside a form view. Suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854320/set-current-date-in-formview